# how to uninstall linux without affecting the windows xp which is in a dual boot

Tags: windows, windows-xp, ubuntu-10.04

i need to uninstall ubuntu from my machine where i have a dual boot with windows xp, i know what to do but problem is to do that i don't have my windows xp cd with me now! now how can i uninstall ubuntu from my machine and reset the windows loader by removing the grub boot loader? is there any such method?

regards, 
Rangana.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are two things you need to do.

1. Restore your master boot record. The best thing to do is to find your XP cdrom and read Microsoft KB article 314058. Else you will need to create a bootable cd/floppy/usb with fdisk on it (see bootdisk.com). You boot and you do `fdisk /mbr`. Some info about this here: http://www.novell.com/coolsolutions/qna/1742.html.
2. Get rid of your ubuntu partition. The simplest and safest thing to do is to reformat your Ubuntu partition from Windows. If you want to merge two partitions together you'll have to find a good software to do that. Parted Magic could help you here.

There is always some degree of risk when doing these things. Backup any important stuff before going forward. You are on your own from here!

Comment: I recommend GParted to remove the Linux partition and resize the Windows one.  http://gparted.sourceforge.net/livecd.php

Comment: Or go into Windows and delete the "unknown" partitions. Boot up XP CD and rebuild MBR and fixboot.